# Extjs 6.0 colorpicker HEX field

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using the [ExtJS colorpicker](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.ux.colorpick.Selector-cfg-layout) to set colors for my website. However I already use certain specific colorcodes that I want. But when I load in the colorpicker, I can't put in my own colorcodes. Does anyone know how to make that field editable? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, the HEX field is lacking the possibility to parse a hex value and set it correctly into all the other fields of the picker - this is why the field is set to `readOnly`.

You can always read, understand and override/extend [the existing code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/source/Selector.html#Ext-ux-colorpick-Selector-method-getMapAndHexRGBFields) to fit your needs.

The field already parses hex color codes correctly if you provide them via `setValue()`, so you would only have to follow that path to find the parse function you can hook into.

I guess it's no more than four hours of work, including testing.

Comment: I'll have to add some validation to make sure no invalid characters are added, but it does work! I used extending classes in order to avoid altering the source. But the HEX field does change the color and saves it to the colorpad. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling with the same issue that sencha was not implementing this functionality. Did the following to make it work:

```
// hex2rgb is missing in sencha so i created a new one
Ext.define('MyAppOverrides.ColorUtils', {
    override   :   'Ext.ux.colorpick.ColorUtils'
    , hex2rgb :   function(hex){
        var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
        return result ? {
            r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
            g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
            b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
        } : null;
    }
});

// When you type the Hex value might not be valid so we have to check first if we get rgb values. If so we just call the parent/original function
Ext.define('MyAppOverrides.SelectorModel', {
    override    :   'Ext.ux.colorpick.SelectorModel'
    , changeRGB: function (rgb) {
        if(rgb){
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    }
}); 


// Was extending the current Ext.ux.colorpick.ColorUtils and made the field writable
var hexField = me.down('textfield[fieldLabel=HEX]');
if(hexField){
      hexField.setReadOnly(false);
}
```

Comment: maybe this approach still needs some love and fine tuning since multiple formats are supported by the colorpicker. My approach uses "#hex6" format. So maybe we need to adjust the hex2rgb function to support mutiple output formats.